# Get filepath of another opened workbook by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA script which collects data from another open file selected by user. Getting data out of the Excel file isn't a problem, but now I want to create a new file in the same folder as the file where the data is from.

I can't get the path of the data file. How can I  do this?

Normally I would do `Application.ThisWorkbook.Path`, I thought for another file I could use `Application.Workbooks(objWB).Path` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Just objWb.Path should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the users file you could set objWB as the ActiveWorkbook and then create a new file from there

```
Sub SaveToActiveFolder()

Dim objWB As Workbook
Set objWB = ActiveWorkbook
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

    With NewWB
        .SaveAs Filename:=objWB.Path & "\NewFile1.xlsm"_
, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

The file NewFile1.xlsm will then be created and saved in the same location as the first file.